# How to solve "unexpected token : A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected" error?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic2

I am writing a code to fire query to firebase. This is the code snippet of my relevant class :

```js
export class ViewUserPage {
  public list = [];
  public ref = firebase.database().ref();
  public usersRef = this.ref.child('users');

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {}
  
  
  this.usersRef.orderByChild('tag').equalTo('staff').on('child_added',function(snap){
    this.list.push(snap.val().email);
    });





}
```

Now the error I'm getting is `"unexpected token : A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected"` in `"this.usersRef.orderByChild"` in the following part of the above snippet :

```js
this.usersRef.orderByChild('tag').equalTo('staff').on('child_added',function(snap){
    this.list.push(snap.val().email);
    });
```

How do I resolve this error? Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe Typescript allows top-level expressions inside a class.

You need to move

```
this.usersRef.orderByChild('tag').equalTo('staff').on('child_added',function(snap){
    this.list.push(snap.val().email);
    });
```

to inside a method. If you expect it to be run when an instance is created, stick it in the constructor. Otherwise put it in some method, and call the method when you want it to be run.

Comment: I think you need to use arrow function to access `this.list`..Not really part of the question though

Comment: @suraj Honestly, my Typescript is too rusty to make that call. I think you're right though if it's the same as Javascript.

Comment: Yes.. typescript is superset of js.. strict type system is just what additional